# Multiple workers on a single machine for different tasks

Tags: python, celery, distributed

I'm trying to build a distributed job execution system with celery.

When I launch 2 workers on a single machine (localhost), in which one for an addition task `add` and the other for a subtraction task `sub`, then use `add.delay()` to kick off sevral addition tasks, there's an error in the subtraction worker's terminal:

`[2013-03-05 15:51:18,898: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'add_tasks.add'.`

In this test, I kicked off 2 addition tasks: one is caught by the addition worker while the other caught by the subtraction worker, which caused the error above. How could I change the configurations so that the second addition task won't be caught by the subtraction worker? Thanks.

Here's the code:

`add_tasks.py:`

```
celery = Celery('add_tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@celery.task
def add(x, y):
    sleep(20)
    return x + y
```

`sub_tasks.py:`

```
celery = Celery('sub_tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@celery.task
def sub(x, y):
    sleep(10)
    return x - y
```

I launched the workers by `celery -A add_tasks worker --loglevel=info -n worker1` and `celery -A sub_tasks worker --loglevel=info -n worker2` in two terminals of localhost machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the `ROUTER` feature could solve my problem. I put my solution here and hope it would be useful to others who have the same problems.

When launching a worker, we could use `-Q queue` option to limit the worker with only accepting tasks in `queue`. In my situation, I used `celery -A add_tasks worker --loglevel=info -n worker1 -Q addition`.

And on the other hand, when kicking off a new task, we should indicate explicitly with queue argument, for example `add.apply_async(queue='addition',priority=0,args=[1,4])` and `sub.apply_async(queue='subtraction',priority=0,args=[1,4])`. Then the addition task won't be accepted by the subtraction worker.